# Get thunderbird to set from equal to "recipient to" when replying to email

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to get thunderbird to set the "from" email address to the email address the email was sent to, when replying to the email.

Example: I am using a google account, and if an email is sent to "something+other@example.com" then the email get sent to my something@example.com account, and when I reply the reply will have the from address something@example.com but I really wish it would have something+other@example.com which was the original recipient address.

This is also an issue when using a catch all account, where I really would like the reply to come from the email address the recipient wrote to.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is invoked in the post
[Bug 327713 - From: address in reply is always set using X-Account-Key: header, even though mail folder owner account does not use "Global Inbox"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327713),
opened 15 years ago (!) and last updated 2 years ago.

I have also taken part in this post, trying in vain to convince the
developers that their method for choosing the reply address is without
any sense.
We all failed in this bug-report, I now think because that part of
Thunderbird is written in such a convoluted manner that no developer
dares to go inside it today.

The only solution I have found was to use the add-on
[Identity Chooser](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/identity-chooser/),
that makes choosing the sender address much more explicit,
so no error is possible,
and in most cases will choose the right return address automatically.
Since I started using it, I haven't done this kind of error again.